# Find method has syntax error when using LookAt

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have not been able to make work this simple command
`$Range.Find($SearchString,LookAt:=xlWhole)`

It returns syntax error. Without `LookAt` works fine, but I need *exact* match

Comment: Which data type is the variable range?

Comment: excel range  ....  '$range = $ws.range("B1").EntireColumn'

Comment: It seems that writing      '$Search = $Range.Find($SearchString,[Type]::Missing,[Type]::Missing,1)'     error disappears

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does not use VBA syntax. That is why you are getting an error. Also, you need to define the parameters you are skipping in place of their defaults in your Excel method calls. This is done with `[Type]::Missing` as you have discovered.

As far as using the [enum for LookAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllookat.aspx) on of the simple things you can do is use the integer representation. 1 in this case is for `xlWhole`.

If you don't want to use magic number you can define your own constants with a simple variable

```
$xlWhole = 1
```

You can, in a way, use the actual constant if you add the assembly that contains these constants.

```
Add-Type -Assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'
$Range.Find($SearchString,[Type]::Missing,[Type]::Missing,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt]::xlWhole)‌​
```